# How to make particles stick to mesh when Molecular Script is enabled?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I’m trying to make particles stick to a mesh and stay on it even if it moves. Setting Friction=1 seems to do the trick **unless** the Molecular Script is enabled. I also tried setting Stickiness=10, but that didn’t help.

Is there any way to make particles stick when Molecular Script is enabled?

With Molecular Script off:

[image]

With Molecular Script on:

[image]

Collision settings:

[image]

Here is the test file:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need molecular script if you already got the results without it?

Comment: @Luciano What I posted here is a very simple example that shows the problem. My actual simulation is much more complex and it has to use Molecular Script on the same particle system.

Comment: @vklidu Did you press "Free All Bakes" and then "Start Molecular Simulation" buttons in Molecular Script UI?

Comment: @vklidu What do you mean by "May I ask for the reason you need achieve that?"

Comment: @vklidu What I posted here is a very simple example that shows the problem. My actual simulation is much more complex and it has to use Molecular Script on the same particle system. It takes about 10 minutes to simulate completely. So I spent some time isolating the issue and posted a file that clearly shows the problem without all the irrelevant details that would make troubleshooting much harder than it should be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maybe have solved it using particles in the lower cubes, and particle linking on collision while simulating everything with molecular. Check the provided blend for more
details. (there is a text file inside, with a few small hints)

Short version: Cube particles are linked on birth, and also perform linking on collision with nearby plane particles.

Note, the particle linking may slow down the simulation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a really ingenious solution. So it seems that Molecular Script somehow overrides friction between particles and a collision object's surface?

Comment: I think Molecular's calculations only happen between particles of particle systems, on which the Molecular script is active. Thats why I think the friction and collisions happen between each particles only, as far as molecular itself is concerned. The regular particle calculations from blender seem to take place too. But molecular is being called as a postprocessing calculation step, and hence I think its calculations override the regular ones.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. So technically that would be some "bad behavior" by Molecular Script.

Answer (score 2):

Behaviour is wierd and I had no luck with proper setup. **This is not an answer**, just some notes to OP – Cubes Physics Properties

Friction 0

[image]

Friction 1

[image]

Friction 1, Stickiness 10

[image]

Result is affected also by speed animation as well, but I never get them on place even with slowmo. It looks like tablecloth effect :)

[image]

Molecular **Substeps** set zero keeps particles on place, but I didn't test it how much affect this other situations. And since substep is needed especially in quick anim, this is not a solution.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the summary and a funny video :)